# Formula to calculate difference in time for specific criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, logical-operators

I am attempting to calculate the downtime of our washers. I have an Excel sheet which displays all our cycle information for our washer machines.

Column B is the start time of the Machine.
Column E is the time difference between one cycle and another.
Column J displays either "None" or "General Washer Error".

What I am attempting is to calculate the time between the last successful Washer Cycle (Where J="None") and the next successful Wash Cycle, but only where there is a failure between them (Where J="General Washer error").

I know I can total the E Column, but this will give me an inaccurate total of downtime as it adds all successful Cycles also.

I have attached an image of the sheet for help.

[image: Excel Sheet Grab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this formula is what you want:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,"<>none")
```

This assumes that System Error Text is actually in column D instead of column J. The image seems to show this, contrary to the description.

**Edit 1**

Ok. Based on your actual worksheet you sent me:

1.) The data in column E are entered into the worksheet as text. They are not numbers. So the SUMIFS() function that I used in my 1st formula will never work for text values. For example, my formula produces a total of zero (not an error) when I open your spreadsheet here with your text values.

2.) Since the formula did not error on my machne I suspect that you are using an older version of Excel that does not include the SUMIFS() function and that is why you get an error instead of a zero.

So, you need a different formula. Here is one that will work in older versions of Excel and it does not care that the values stored in column E are actually text instead of true numbers:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D3:D2002<>"none")*(E3:E2002))
```

Comment: Hi Excel Hero, this is giving me a "#NAME?" error. Any ideas.

Comment: @Uhujkill Hi. I just tried it again here and it works with the sample data I'm using based on your image. It's probably something really small. Is there a way you can email me a very small sampling of data in a workbook with my formula error-ing? Pretty sure I can fix it right away for you then. My email address is: daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: Should be in your inbox. Thanks

Comment: @Uhujkill I edited my answer with a new formula based on the data in your worksheet.

Comment: Hi Excel Hero, sorry about the lack of information. My department hasn't been updated to the newer version of Excel, yet! The edited formula you provided worked successfully. Thanks for your help!